# Multiple GridLayouts, each one contains TextView with same ID, retrieve only this inside specific GridLayout

Tags: android

I got 16 `GridLayouts` and inside them I got one `TextView` with same ID for each `GridLayout`. I want to find only this `TextView` which is inside of `gridLayout1` or `gridLayout2` etc. Is that possible?

```
switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.gridLayout1:
findViewById(R.id.textView)
case R.id.gridLayout2:
findViewById(R.id.textView)
....
case R.id.gridLayout16:
findViewById(R.id.textView)
```

Comment: use parent view to access the child. In your case, gridlayout1.findViewBbyId(R.id.textview). Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you perform findViewById on the specific GridLayout, you should be able to find that specific TextView. 
Try this code:

```
switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.gridLayout1:
      view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
      break;
   case R.id.gridLayout2:
      view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
      break;
   ....
   case R.id.gridLayout16:
      view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
      break;
```

But notice that actually you don't need this switch statement.

Comment: switch is for onClick purposes for each grid

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the textview inside gridLayout1 just use

```
gridLayout1.findViewById(R.id.textview);
```